# SQL - Having aggregation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I'm using MySQL and writing this query :

```
select gauno, count(potno)
from druide_potion
group by gauno
having count(potno) = min(count(potno))
```

But Mysql says : "#1111 - Invalid use of group function".

In what is this request incorrect? (When I remove the HAVING, I haven't the error but haven't the result expected as well).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the having clause, each aggregate returns only one value, so requesting the `min()` of `count()` makes no sense.

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
select  *
from    druide_potion
group by
        gauno
having  count(potno) = 
        (
        select  count(potno)
        from    druide_potion
        group by
                gauno
        order by
                 count(potno)
        limit 1
        )
```

This would return all `gauno` with the minimum amount of rows with a non-null `potno` column.

Comment: On Sybase it returns me a result, they are no other way to search what I need ? That seems to be too complicated, I think their is a better way ...

Answer (score 0):

```
select gauno, count(potno)
  from druide_potion
 group by gauno
 order by count(potno)
 limit 1
```

Comment: If there's multiple gauno with the lowest `count(potno)`, this would return only one

Answer (score 0):

Proper ANSI query

```
SELECT D.*
FROM
(
    select min(cnt) MinCount
    FROM
    (
        select gauno, count(potno) cnt
        from druide_potion
        group by gauno
    )
    Counted1
) MinCounted
inner join
(
    select gauno, count(potno) Cnt
    from druide_potion
    group by gauno
) Counted2
    on MinCounted.MinCount = Counted.Cnt
inner join druide_potion D
    ON D.gauno = Counted2.gauno
```